# Split a big Jira-Rest-Request

Tags: java, rest, jira

I'm looking for an opportunity to split a big request like:
 `rest/api/2/search?jql=(project in (project1, project2, project3....project10)) AND issuetype = Bug AND (component not in (projectA, projectB) OR component = EMPTY)`. The result will containe > 500 Bugs -> It's very very slow. I want to get them with different requests (methode to performe the request will be annotated with @Asynchronous) but the jql needs to be the same. I don't want to search separately for project1, project2...project10. Would be nice if someone has an idea to resolve my problem.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to calculate pagination. First get the metadata.

```
rest/api/2/search?jql=[complete search query]&fields=*none&maxResults=0
```

you should get something like this:

```
{"startAt":0,"maxResults":0,"total":100,"issues":[]}
```

so completely without fields, just pagination metadata.

Than create search URI like this.

```
   rest/api/2/search?jql=[complete search query]&startAt=0&maxResults=10
   rest/api/2/search?jql=[complete search query]&startAt=10&maxResults=10
   ..etc
```

Beware data should change so you should be prepared that you won't recieve all the data and also pagination metadata if calculation is expensive (exspecially "total") should not be presented. More [Paged API](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/7.0-SNAPSHOT/)

Answer (score 0):

Can you not break into 2 parts? If you are displaying in a web page ( display what you can without performance hit. If its a report then get all objects gradually and show once completed.

1. Get the count in total for JQL & just get the minimum information needed for step 2 - assume its 900
2. Use the pagination feature (maxResults=100) make multiple calls.
3. Work on each request.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to run the two requests at once and need paging of bugs by user request, you can:

1. Make a request with the 'maxResults' property set to how much you need.
2. On the next request set the 'maxResults' property and the 'startAt' with the same value.
3. If you need to fetch more data, make new request with the same 'maxResults' but update 'startAt' to be the count of bugs you fetched in the previous requests.